# How to know list of available endpoints allowed from vault AppRoleId+AppSecret?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I tried login with AppRoleId, and got 2 policy: `default`, `xx-cred-policy`

```
                Auth:          &api.SecretAuth{
                    ClientToken:      "s.UZ*censored*3l",
                    Accessor:         "HU*censored*g",
                    Policies:         {"default", "xx-cred-policy"},
                    TokenPolicies:    {"default", "xx-cred-policy"},
```

When I tried to hit `/sys/policy/:policyName` (replace policyName with `default` or `xx-cred-policy`, I got 403, Is there any way to know which endpoints are allowed with that AppRoleId?

I need to know whether I can create another AppRoleId from this AppRoleId or not at least, also which secret endpoint that that AppRoleId allowed to write.

Comment: Via the same Go SDK in your question, API, CLI, or other?

Comment: @MattSchuchard go sdk would be best

Comment: Actually it appears that may not be available: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/vault/api@v1.9.2

Comment: oh so it's possible to do this using other programming language or vault client? @MattSchuchard

Comment: Closest is https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/token/capabilities and https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/system/capabilities-self, but this requires paths as an input and not output.